# Xml Parsing from URL and saving in to documents directory in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

hi guys can any one suggest me any tutorial for " how to download the XML from the URL, stores it as an XML file in the documents folder"
thanks.

Comment: Using TBXML library you can download XML directly from url.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you.

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://www.Sample.com/Sample.xml";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:
          [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
           NSASCIIStringEncoding]];


NSData *xmldata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

NSString *documentsDir =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedxml.xml"];
[xmldata writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

Hope  this Helps !!!